# Ошибка интернет магазина на Opencart 3

Tags: opencart

Недавно крашнулся магазин на opencart. Появляется вот такая ошибка:

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'bh62986_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 7Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: 
Error No: ' in /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/system/library/db/mysqli.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/system/library/db.php(31): DB\MySQLi->__construct('localhost', 'bh62986_admin', 'hopesh27shop', 'bh62986_sewings...', '3306') #1 /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/system/framework.php(80): DB->__construct('mysqli', 'localhost', 'bh62986_admin', 'hopesh27shop', 'bh62986_sewings...', '3306') #2 /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/system/startup.php(104): require_once('/home/bh62986/s...') #3 /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/index.php(19): start('catalog') #4 {main} thrown in /home/bh62986/sewingshop.hopesh.ru/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10

Но самому очень трудно разобрать в каком файле искать проблему, и может кто сталкивался с подобным, буду рад помощи

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25174218/5441023

Comment: просто крашнулся? что-нить делалось на хосте? какая версия магазина?

Comment: просто правильно настройте подключение к бд

Answer (score 2):

Если ничего не трогали - обращайтесь в техподдержку хостера. Возможно они меняли сервера и где-то накосячили.
Но сперва проверьте config.php, admin/config.php. Сверьте значения констант данных бд с действительными.

```
// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'mysql_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mysql_password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'mysql_db');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```